# Magento 1.9.4.3 Logged in users cant create order but guests can

Tags: magento-1.9

If a user on our site is logged in and they try to create an order the checkout page just refreshes when they click complete order and no order is created.

If a guest tries to order it works fine.

Is there any noticeable difference in the way the order is processed when a user is logged in?

This started to happen after we upgraded the site to 1.9.4.3 from 1.7

There seems to be 2 relevant errors in the system log:

**> ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: custom  in /home/storm/sites/quickplaysport-com/public/app/code/local/Magestore/Onestepcheckout/Model/Observer.php on line 212**

and

**ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /home/storm/sites/quickplaysport-com/public/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4039**

any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like your using a third party module (Magestore/Onestepcheckout) if you've upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9 I would expect some changes have occurred so I'd reach out to the plugin developers to get the latest edition which may be more compatible with that version.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a google recapture plugin conflict, it was trying to check a recapture box for the customer login on the checkout page which didnt actually exist. The error message was hidden by another element.